# Accessing SBElementArray content from Scripting-Bridge in swift

Tags: swift, casting, itunes, scripting-bridge

I've been trying to use, in a swift code, the various SBElementArray generators defined in the iTunes.h ScriptingBridge header, for example:

- List of playlists:  `(SBElementArray<iTunesPlaylist *> *) playlists;`
- List of artworks associated to a track: `(SBElementArray<iTunesArtwork *> *) artworks;`

But when i try to use a method associated to the type contained in those array:

```
let playlists: SBElementArray = iTunes.playlists()
if let playlist = playlists[0] as? iTunesPlaylist {
    print(playlist.name)
}
```

I get a compile error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_iTunesPlaylist", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This seems to be limited to the SBElementArray as I have no problem accessing current track name with the following :

```
let track: iTunesTrack = iTunes.currentTrack;
print(track.name)
```

I'm also guessing that it has something to do with the type casting I'm trying to do from 'anyObject' to 'iTunesPlaylist' in my code (which i think i need to be bale to access the playlist content or whatever artwork i would like to display), because the following code:

```
let playlists: SBElementArray = iTunes.playlists()
print(playlists[0])
print(type(of: playlists[0]))
```

corectly returns:

```
<ITunesPlaylist @0x6080000402d0: ITunesPlaylist 0 of application "iTunes" (93931)>
ITunesPlaylist
```

Comment: One difference I notice is: I vs i (`iTunesPlaylist`/`ITunesPlaylist`)

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I actually tried to add the class ITunesPlaylist (with capital i) to the iTunes.h file in desperation, but it didn't change the result. I'm going to give it another go, more carefully, just to make sure

Comment: So i tried replacing every iTunesPlaylist with ITunesPlaylist (with capital i) this time, both in the iTunes.h file and in my AppDelegate.swift file. Still get the same compile error.

Comment: The exact same error? Or does it have an upper case I now?

Comment: You right, it has a upper case now : `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ITunesPlaylist", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what the issue could be. Is it possible for you to share your project somewhere?

Comment: I'll try to put it on Github, probably tomorrow or friday. Just have to learn how to first :) I've started coding on my off time a few month ago so still discovering

Comment: Anyway, thanks for taking an interest in my "coding roadblock", it's been driving crazy !

Comment: So I've added the project on GitHub : https://github.com/Ericvulpi/MusicBar

Comment: The artwork part is in the updateDisplay() function in the AppDelegate file (in comment to keep the rest working)

Comment: Are you aware of macOS's [iTunesLibrary framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/ituneslibrary)? If you only need read access you'll find it far less painful than SB, which is a sack of knackers. It also saves you having to launch iTunes just to get info from it, which can be irritating to users. If you need more control than iTunesLibrary allows, another option is to include AppleScripts in your app and call their handlers directly via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge; AS may be crap as a language but at least its Apple event bridge works right.

Comment: I didn't know about iTunesLibrary framework, i'll give it a try for sure, thanks. I chose scripting bridge over applescript because it looked simpler, but having lost hours on the non-sense described above, i'm not so sure any more ...

Answer (score 0):

The downcasting is trying to create an optional and initialize an iTunesPlaylist that is not allowed and not present in the linker. Force it as you always know it to be a iTunesPlaylist or check the type.

```
if playlists.count > 0 {
    let playlist : = playlists[0]
    if playlist is iTunesPlaylist {
        print(playlist.name)
    }
}
```